# first order differential equations, linear and nonlinear equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

State where in the ty-plane the hypotheses of Theroem 2.4.2 are satisfied.

$$y' = \frac{2t-3y}{2t+5y}$$

Are there any tips or solutions on how to do this one? thanks.

EDIT: I tried to write down theorem 2.4.2 but it wouldn't show up after posting question, I don't know why.

Comment: OK I will try again. let the functions f and af/ay be continous in some rectangle alpha < t < beta, gamma < y < delta containg the point (t0, y0). Then, in some interval t0-h < t < t0+h contained in alpha < t < beta, there is a unique solution y = ø(t) of the initial value problem y'=f(t,y), y(t0)=y0, you could check out https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m22b/22BsolnsHW2.pdf if you scroll down to sections 2.4, with basically an example problem, but I dont understand anything of that

Answer (score 0):

The ODE, which is an ODE of the homogeneous kind, can be analytically solved in so far we accept that the solution be given on a parametric form (parameter $z$ in attachment)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The hypotheses of the theorem are that $f$ and $\frac{\partial f }{ \partial y}$ are both continuous on a small rectangle containing $(t_{0},y_{0}).$ In that case, we can find a unique solution of the DE in a small region around $(t_{0},y_{0})$. In this case, $$ f(t,y) = \frac{2t-3y}{2t-5y},$$ so that $$\frac{ \partial f }{\partial y} = \frac{-6t+15y + 10t - 15y}{(2t-5y)^{2}} = \frac{4t}{(2t-5y)^{2}}.$$ The only place a rational function is discontinuous is inputs that make us try and divide by 0, so as long as $2t-5y \neq 0$, we're ok. So as long as the rectangle doesn't include any points where $2t-5y = 0$, i.e. as long at it doesn't have any points on the line $y = \frac{2}{5}t$, then the theorem applies.